# How to chat with other devices as well (channels)?

Tags: django, django-channels

i am a beginner in django and right now studying about django-channels. I have implemented chat application successfully but obviously i cannot test it on other devices. Please help me how to connect and chat with other devices ?

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the local host, you can not connect to anything from that ip. You need an IP that is on a public or local network, to connect to other defices.